# How to bring up the front page with errors like this - Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

This is coding in view-layout-default

```
<ul class="nav">
            <!-- load data menu dari /element/menu -->
            <?php 
            echo $this->element('mainmenu');
             ?>

           <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="../"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Beranda</a>
                </li></ul>
```

[image: default]

Answer (score 0):

@zen, you are already bringing up the frontpage like that. You need to provide us the content of `mainmenu` element. Typically that is located at `/src/Template/Element/mainmenu.ctp`. We should then be able to guide into what is wrong, if that is what you are asking.Based on CakePHP convention, this element might be request `/instance/` and that is not available.